# serverfault retag webhosting -> web-hosting

Tags: support, retag-request

On serverfault

`web-hosting` has 226 questions vs. `webhosting` with 21 questions.

Please retag `webhosting` -> `web-hosting`.

Answer (score 2):

I've merged the tags. I also reviewed and removed/merged the "webhost" tag which in all six cases was used as synonym to "web-hosting."